# SharePoint 2016 Backup Phase In Process - Readiness No Backup or restore in progress

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm having an issue, I believe with my timer services. It began with a wsp that would not deploy (stuck in scheduled to deploy).

I'm trying to run a backup and I believe it has ran, however, it is stuck in phase "in process". I have deleted the job from the definitions page, recycled sp timer, reset iis and even restarted windows and can't get the backup to finish.

I have also checked the DBs to ensure that they aren't in read-only

I'm receiving a number of ULS errors for search service application as it is paused for backup/restore as well.

Any other suggestions to get this to update?

Comment: I *believe* my issue was related to Symantec Backup Exec. I removed the client, restarted system and noted that the backup was able to start/run/finish. Unfortunately, the Search Service Application and AppFabricCaching both became corrupted and required rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following script to check if Timer Service instance is disabled

```
$farm  = Get-SPFarm $disabledTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances | where {$_.Status -ne "Online"} if ($disabledTimers -ne $null) {
    foreach ($timer in $disabledTimers)
    {
        Write-Host "Timer service instance on server " $timer.Server.Name " is not Online. Current status:" $timer.Status
        Write-Host "Attempting to set the status of the service instance to online"
        $timer.Status = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPObjectStatus]::Online
        $timer.Update()
    } } else {
    Write-Host "All Timer Service Instances in the farm are online! No problems found" }
```